# Question about option premiums

Tags: options

Is there any conceivable way in which an OTM  option's value will decrease or (will not move, for that matter) as the underlying moves in a direction that gets the option closer to the money, aside from decay attributed to time value?

If so do you know of any examples in which this has ever happened?

Comment: Volatility collapse. An example would be after earnings.

Comment: what about for long term options of about a year which include 3 or 4 earning's dates, would they experience the same effect?

Comment: just to a lesser extent, but yes

Comment: When demand is higher the risk gets higher, so the price goes higher.

Answer (score 1):

1. Lack of liquidity in the options market (wide spreads)
2. Decrease in volatility.
3. Decrease in demand (or reduction of implied volatility)

Examples

1. Look right after the open or a few seconds before the close.
2. After the stock has made a big run up in price.
3. After an earnings announcement.